# process a list of files with a specific extension name in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I process all the files with ".xyz" extension in a folder? The basic idea is that I want a list of file names and then a for loop to load each file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`dir()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) to obtain a list of filenames.  You can specify wildcards.

Answer (score 28):

As others have already mentioned, you should use the DIR function to list files in a directory.

If you are still looking, here is an example to show how to use the function:

```
dirName = 'C:\path\to\folder';              %# folder path
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.xyz') );   %# list all *.xyz files
files = {files.name}';                      %'# file names

data = cell(numel(files),1);                %# store file contents
for i=1:numel(files)
    fname = fullfile(dirName,files{i});     %# full path to file
    data{i} = myLoadFunction(fname);        %# load file
end
```

Of course, you would have to supply the function that actually reads and parses the XYZ files.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

`fileName=ls('*xyz')`.

fileName variable will have the list of all the filenames which you can use in the for loop

Comment: Be careful, [ls](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/ls.html) returns a different syntax on Windows or Unix!

Comment: This will pad space to the filenames and make them equal length, which is not good.

Comment: @LWZ: unnecessary space can be remove with the standard strtrim function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
dirName = 'E:\My Matlab\5';
[sub,fls] = subdir(dirName);
D = [];
j = 1;
for i=1:length(sub),
    files{i} = dir( fullfile(sub{i},'*.xyz') );
    if length(files{i})==1
        D(j) = i; 
        files_s{j} = sub{i}; 
        j=j+1;
    end
end
```

varaible `files_s` returns the desire paths that contain those specific data types!

The subdir function can be found at:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1492-subdir--new-