# Load multiple .mat files for processing

Tags: matlab, iteration, matlab-load

In MatLab I have (after extensive code running) multiple .mat files outputted to .mat files. The actual matlab name of each .mat file is called `results` but I've used the `save` command to write them to different files. A small subset of the files looks like this:

```
results_test1_1.mat
results_test1_2.mat
results_test1_3.mat
results_test1_4.mat

results_test2_1.mat
results_test2_2.mat
results_test2_3.mat
results_test2_4.mat
```

Now I want to compare the results for each test, which means I have to load in all four .mat files and combine them in a graph. Reading in one file and making the eventual graph is no problem. But since all files have the same matlab name `results`, iteratively loading them is not an option (at least, not one that I know of yet) since in the end only file 4 remains since it rewrites the previous ones.

Is there a way to load all these files and store them in different variables in a structure (regarding only one test set)? Because doing all this manually is a hell of a lot of work.

I've tried to use this method: [Load Multiple .mat Files to Matlab workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498116/load-multiple-mat-files-to-matlab-workspace) but I get an `Invalid field name` error on `loaded.(char(file)) = load(file);`

Comment: Somewhat similar questions [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366374/how-can-i-load-100-files-with-similar-names-and-or-string-in-just-one-step-in-ma) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366374/how-can-i-load-100-files-with-similar-names-and-or-string-in-just-one-step-in-ma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `load` into a variable (preferably a cell array)

```
results = cell( 2, 4 ); % allocate
for testi=1:2
    for resi = 1:4
        filename = sprintf('results_test%d_%d.mat', testi, resi );
        results{testi,resi} = load( filename );
    end
end
```

Now you have all the results stored in `results` cell array and you may access the stored variables, e.g.,

```
results{1,3}.someVar % access variable someVar (assuming such variable was saves to the corresponding mat file
```