# matlab-need to load file whose filename is stored in a variable

Tags: matlab

I have loaded certain arrays in matlab and I want to take means and stuff, but my problem is that 'M' *which is a variable*( it is in the code that i have attached) is treated as a `char` rather than as an array(which it actually is). How to make use of M, the array instead of M, the `char`?

```
kk=[];
files = dir('*.dat');
for i=1:length(files)
    eval(['load ' files(i).name])
    M=files(i).name;
    load(M)
    p=mean(M,2);
    kk=[kk p];
end
mn= mean(kk,2);
```

Comment: have you tried `load(M(:))` or `load(M(:)')`? Also what's the point of the `eval` line or is that what you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030172/load-multiple-mat-files-for-processing) - it is quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

Several comments:

1. You can `load` into a variable `M` instead of assigning the file name to `M`

   ```
   >> M = load( files(ii).name ); % load the file into a matrix M
   ```
2. If you want to compute the `mean` of all numbers stored in all the files, then `mean( [mean(M1,2) mean(M2,2) ...] )` is not necessarily the `mean` what you want.
   If there is a different number of columns in the different matrices, then you are not computing the desired quantitiy. **Make sure you are computing the right quantity you are looking for**.
3. **Do not use `eval`**: it is unnecessary, makes the code difficult to read and hard to maintain and debug.
4. Do not grow an array inside a loop: `kk = [kk p];`. This kind of behavior **kills** Matlab's performance, because it needs to re-allocate `kk` at each iteration. Pre-allocate the memory required for `kk` before the loop - you'll see a significant speedup.
5. In Matlab, [it is best not to use `i` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `importdata` function with some text processing for the filename:

```
M=importdata(['/path/to/file/' num2str(j) '.dat'])
```

or

```
M=load(['/path/to/file/' num2str(j) '.dat'])
```

Also, you can try `dlmread` in your case. I think `load` is more proper for MAT files. Here is a comparison of different ways:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html